# error: syntax error from if clause

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

```
String jk = "where nam='" + txt1.getText() + "'";
String ik = "and password='" + txt2.getPassword() + " ' ";
String sql;
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" + jk + ik;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

the error has been occurring its syntax error in from clause.

Comment: this seems wrong, both in syntax and in logic: +jk+ik

Comment: You need spaces before `where` and `and`.

Comment: There is also a space after the password and before the closing `'`, which will make it not work. Also, is the column really named `nam`? Or is it `name`? It's very important to be precise and not sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String jk =" where nam='"+txt1.getText()+"'";                
String ik =" and password='"+txt2.getPassword()+" ' ";                                              

    String sql;                 
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" +jk+ik;                        
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

You forgot to add spaces between "where" and "and"
Also I feel that nam will be name in the table column

Comment: Please select this as your answer by clicking the tick mark

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
String jk =" where nam='"+txt1.getText()+"'";        //note the space before where
String ik =" and password='"+txt2.getPassword()+" '  //and space before and
String sql;                 
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" +jk+ik;                        
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

**Initially your query looked following**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1where nam='xyz'and password='xyz';
```

**After spaces**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 where nam='xyz' and password='xyz';
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such errors in future I can recommend the `PreparedStatement`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) is the Oracle tutorial.

```
String stmnt = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE nam=? and password=?;";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(stmnt);
pstmt.setString(1, txt1.getText());
pstmt.setString(2, txt2.getText());
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Not only to avoid these errors, but also to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

When you are combining jk and ik wih sql there is no space between table name and where clause. That is why u r getting the error. Have a spece there

```
String jk =" where nam='"+txt1.getText()+"'";                
String ik =" and password='"+txt2.getPassword()+" ' ";                               String sql;                 
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" +jk+ik;                        
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a blank between `jk` and `ik`

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" +jk+" "+ik;
```

But it is better to learn about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces between `from` and `where` clause.

```
String jk ="where nam='"+txt1.getText()+"'";
String ik ="and password='"+txt2.getPassword()+" ' "; String sql;
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" + " " + jk + " " + ik; rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String jk =" where nam='"+txt1.getText()+"' ";
String ik ="and password='"+txt2.getPassword()+"'";     
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1" +jk+ik;                        
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

this should work fine..!
cheers happy coding.. :)